# Which platform of Ubuntu Server should i choose with i686 cpu?

Tags: 14.04, server, 64-bit, cpu, 32-bit

I bring back to life quite ancient desktop machine (as i think) which was used as server. In the process of revision of hardware and software and stumble upon a fact i don't know which version of Ubuntu Server choose to update it. At first i feel like it must be Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (32-bit), but things start playing with my mind real soon.

```
> free -g

                total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             3          0          2          0          0          0

-/+ buffers/cache:          0          3
Swap:            2          0          2


> getconf LONG_BIT
  32

> lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty


> uname -a

Linux aristarhys-server 4.4.0-45-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 15:07:39 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

> lscpu

Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 4
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               3200.000
BogoMIPS:              6431.01
L1d cache:             16K
L2 cache:              2048K

> cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 4
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x5
cpu MHz     : 3200.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr
bugs        :
bogomips    : 6431.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

> lshw -c cpu
  *-cpu                   
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: 15.4.3
       serial: 0000-0F43-0000-0000-0000-0000
       slot: Socket 775
       size: 3200MHz
       capacity: 4GHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 200MHz
       capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx x86-64 constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr cpufreq
       configuration: id=1
     *-logicalcpu:0
          description: Logical CPU
          physical id: 1.1
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: logical
     *-logicalcpu:1
          description: Logical CPU
          physical id: 1.2
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: logical

cpuid
CPU 0:
   vendor_id = "GenuineIntel"
   version information (1/eax):
      processor type  = primary processor (0)
      family          = Intel Pentium 4/Pentium D/Pentium Extreme Edition/Celeron/Xeon/Xeon MP/Itanium2, AMD Athlon 64/Athlon XP-M/Opteron/Sempron/Turion (15)
      model           = 0x4 (4)
      stepping id     = 0x3 (3)
      extended family = 0x0 (0)
      extended model  = 0x0 (0)
      (simple synth)  = Intel Pentium 4 (Prescott N0) / Xeon (Nocona N0 / Irwindale N0), 90nm
   miscellaneous (1/ebx):
      process local APIC physical ID = 0x0 (0)
      cpu count                      = 0x2 (2)
      CLFLUSH line size              = 0x8 (8)
      brand index                    = 0x0 (0)
   brand id = 0x00 (0): unknown
   feature information (1/edx):
      x87 FPU on chip                        = true
      virtual-8086 mode enhancement          = true
      debugging extensions                   = true
      page size extensions                   = true
      time stamp counter                     = true
      RDMSR and WRMSR support                = true
      physical address extensions            = true
      machine check exception                = true
      CMPXCHG8B inst.                        = true
      APIC on chip                           = true
      SYSENTER and SYSEXIT                   = true
      memory type range registers            = true
      PTE global bit                         = true
      machine check architecture             = true
      conditional move/compare instruction   = true
      page attribute table                   = true
      page size extension                    = true
      processor serial number                = false
      CLFLUSH instruction                    = true
      debug store                            = true
      thermal monitor and clock ctrl         = true
      MMX Technology                         = true
      FXSAVE/FXRSTOR                         = true
      SSE extensions                         = true
      SSE2 extensions                        = true
      self snoop                             = true
      hyper-threading / multi-core supported = true
      therm. monitor                         = true
      IA64                                   = false
      pending break event                    = true
   feature information (1/ecx):
      PNI/SSE3: Prescott New Instructions     = true
      PCLMULDQ instruction                    = false
      64-bit debug store                      = true
      MONITOR/MWAIT                           = true
      CPL-qualified debug store               = true
      VMX: virtual machine extensions         = false
      SMX: safer mode extensions              = false
      Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology     = true
      thermal monitor 2                       = false
      SSSE3 extensions                        = false
      context ID: adaptive or shared L1 data  = true
      FMA instruction                         = false
      CMPXCHG16B instruction                  = true
      xTPR disable                            = true
      perfmon and debug                       = false
      process context identifiers             = false
      direct cache access                     = false
      SSE4.1 extensions                       = false
      SSE4.2 extensions                       = false
      extended xAPIC support                  = false
      MOVBE instruction                       = false
      POPCNT instruction                      = false
      time stamp counter deadline             = false
      AES instruction                         = false
      XSAVE/XSTOR states                      = false
      OS-enabled XSAVE/XSTOR                  = false
      AVX: advanced vector extensions         = false
      F16C half-precision convert instruction = false
      RDRAND instruction                      = false
      hypervisor guest status                 = false
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x50: instruction TLB: 4K & 2M/4M pages, 64 entries
      0x5b: data TLB: 4K & 4M pages, 64 entries
      0x60: L1 data cache: 16K, 8-way, 64 byte lines
      0x40: No L3 cache
      0x70: Trace cache: 12K-uop, 8-way
      0x7d: L2 cache: 2M, 8-way, sectored, 64 byte lines
   processor serial number: 0000-0F43-0000-0000-0000-0000
   deterministic cache parameters (4):
      --- cache 0 ---
      cache type                           = data cache (1)
      cache level                          = 0x1 (1)
      self-initializing cache level        = true
      fully associative cache              = false
      extra threads sharing this cache     = 0x1 (1)
      extra processor cores on this die    = 0x0 (0)
      system coherency line size           = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions             = 0x0 (0)
      ways of associativity                = 0x7 (7)
      WBINVD/INVD behavior on lower caches = false
      inclusive to lower caches            = false
      complex cache indexing               = false
      number of sets - 1 (s)               = 31
      --- cache 1 ---
      cache type                           = unified cache (3)
      cache level                          = 0x2 (2)
      self-initializing cache level        = true
      fully associative cache              = false
      extra threads sharing this cache     = 0x1 (1)
      extra processor cores on this die    = 0x0 (0)
      system coherency line size           = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions             = 0x1 (1)
      ways of associativity                = 0x7 (7)
      WBINVD/INVD behavior on lower caches = false
      inclusive to lower caches            = false
      complex cache indexing               = false
      number of sets - 1 (s)               = 2047
   MONITOR/MWAIT (5):
      smallest monitor-line size (bytes)       = 0x40 (64)
      largest monitor-line size (bytes)        = 0x40 (64)
      enum of Monitor-MWAIT exts supported     = false
      supports intrs as break-event for MWAIT  = false
      number of C0 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C1 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C2 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C3 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C4 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C5 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C6 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C7 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
   extended feature flags (0x80000001/edx):
      SYSCALL and SYSRET instructions        = false
      execution disable                      = true
      1-GB large page support                = false
      RDTSCP                                 = false
      64-bit extensions technology available = true
   Intel feature flags (0x80000001/ecx):
      LAHF/SAHF supported in 64-bit mode     = false
      LZCNT advanced bit manipulation        = false
      3DNow! PREFETCH/PREFETCHW instructions = false
   brand = "              Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz"
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = 0x0 (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = 0x0 (0)
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = 0x0 (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = 0x0 (0)
   L1 data cache information (0x80000005/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x0 (0)
      size (Kb)         = 0x0 (0)
   L1 instruction cache information (0x80000005/edx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x0 (0)
      size (Kb)         = 0x0 (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 unified cache information (0x80000006/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x40 (64)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 8-way (6)
      size (Kb)         = 0x800 (2048)
   L3 cache information (0x80000006/edx):
      line size (bytes)     = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag         = 0x0 (0)
      associativity         = L2 off (0)
      size (in 512Kb units) = 0x0 (0)
   Advanced Power Management Features (0x80000007/edx):
      temperature sensing diode      = false
      frequency ID (FID) control     = false
      voltage ID (VID) control       = false
      thermal trip (TTP)             = false
      thermal monitor (TM)           = false
      software thermal control (STC) = false
      100 MHz multiplier control     = false
      hardware P-State control       = false
      TscInvariant                   = false
   Physical Address and Linear Address Size (0x80000008/eax):
      maximum physical address bits         = 0x24 (36)
      maximum linear (virtual) address bits = 0x30 (48)
      maximum guest physical address bits   = 0x0 (0)
   Logical CPU cores (0x80000008/ecx):
      number of CPU cores - 1 = 0x0 (0)
      ApicIdCoreIdSize        = 0x0 (0)
   (multi-processing synth): hyper-threaded (t=2)
   (multi-processing method): Intel leaf 1/4
   (APIC widths synth): CORE_width=0 SMT_width=1
   (APIC synth): PKG_ID=0 CORE_ID=0 SMT_ID=0
   (synth) = Intel Pentium 4 (Prescott N0), 90nm
CPU 1:
   vendor_id = "GenuineIntel"
   version information (1/eax):
      processor type  = primary processor (0)
      family          = Intel Pentium 4/Pentium D/Pentium Extreme Edition/Celeron/Xeon/Xeon MP/Itanium2, AMD Athlon 64/Athlon XP-M/Opteron/Sempron/Turion (15)
      model           = 0x4 (4)
      stepping id     = 0x3 (3)
      extended family = 0x0 (0)
      extended model  = 0x0 (0)
      (simple synth)  = Intel Pentium 4 (Prescott N0) / Xeon (Nocona N0 / Irwindale N0), 90nm
   miscellaneous (1/ebx):
      process local APIC physical ID = 0x1 (1)
      cpu count                      = 0x2 (2)
      CLFLUSH line size              = 0x8 (8)
      brand index                    = 0x0 (0)
   brand id = 0x00 (0): unknown
   feature information (1/edx):
      x87 FPU on chip                        = true
      virtual-8086 mode enhancement          = true
      debugging extensions                   = true
      page size extensions                   = true
      time stamp counter                     = true
      RDMSR and WRMSR support                = true
      physical address extensions            = true
      machine check exception                = true
      CMPXCHG8B inst.                        = true
      APIC on chip                           = true
      SYSENTER and SYSEXIT                   = true
      memory type range registers            = true
      PTE global bit                         = true
      machine check architecture             = true
      conditional move/compare instruction   = true
      page attribute table                   = true
      page size extension                    = true
      processor serial number                = false
      CLFLUSH instruction                    = true
      debug store                            = true
      thermal monitor and clock ctrl         = true
      MMX Technology                         = true
      FXSAVE/FXRSTOR                         = true
      SSE extensions                         = true
      SSE2 extensions                        = true
      self snoop                             = true
      hyper-threading / multi-core supported = true
      therm. monitor                         = true
      IA64                                   = false
      pending break event                    = true
   feature information (1/ecx):
      PNI/SSE3: Prescott New Instructions     = true
      PCLMULDQ instruction                    = false
      64-bit debug store                      = true
      MONITOR/MWAIT                           = true
      CPL-qualified debug store               = true
      VMX: virtual machine extensions         = false
      SMX: safer mode extensions              = false
      Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology     = true
      thermal monitor 2                       = false
      SSSE3 extensions                        = false
      context ID: adaptive or shared L1 data  = true
      FMA instruction                         = false
      CMPXCHG16B instruction                  = true
      xTPR disable                            = true
      perfmon and debug                       = false
      process context identifiers             = false
      direct cache access                     = false
      SSE4.1 extensions                       = false
      SSE4.2 extensions                       = false
      extended xAPIC support                  = false
      MOVBE instruction                       = false
      POPCNT instruction                      = false
      time stamp counter deadline             = false
      AES instruction                         = false
      XSAVE/XSTOR states                      = false
      OS-enabled XSAVE/XSTOR                  = false
      AVX: advanced vector extensions         = false
      F16C half-precision convert instruction = false
      RDRAND instruction                      = false
      hypervisor guest status                 = false
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x50: instruction TLB: 4K & 2M/4M pages, 64 entries
      0x5b: data TLB: 4K & 4M pages, 64 entries
      0x60: L1 data cache: 16K, 8-way, 64 byte lines
      0x40: No L3 cache
      0x70: Trace cache: 12K-uop, 8-way
      0x7d: L2 cache: 2M, 8-way, sectored, 64 byte lines
   processor serial number: 0000-0F43-0000-0000-0000-0000
   deterministic cache parameters (4):
      --- cache 0 ---
      cache type                           = data cache (1)
      cache level                          = 0x1 (1)
      self-initializing cache level        = true
      fully associative cache              = false
      extra threads sharing this cache     = 0x1 (1)
      extra processor cores on this die    = 0x0 (0)
      system coherency line size           = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions             = 0x0 (0)
      ways of associativity                = 0x7 (7)
      WBINVD/INVD behavior on lower caches = false
      inclusive to lower caches            = false
      complex cache indexing               = false
      number of sets - 1 (s)               = 31
      --- cache 1 ---
      cache type                           = unified cache (3)
      cache level                          = 0x2 (2)
      self-initializing cache level        = true
      fully associative cache              = false
      extra threads sharing this cache     = 0x1 (1)
      extra processor cores on this die    = 0x0 (0)
      system coherency line size           = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions             = 0x1 (1)
      ways of associativity                = 0x7 (7)
      WBINVD/INVD behavior on lower caches = false
      inclusive to lower caches            = false
      complex cache indexing               = false
      number of sets - 1 (s)               = 2047
   MONITOR/MWAIT (5):
      smallest monitor-line size (bytes)       = 0x40 (64)
      largest monitor-line size (bytes)        = 0x40 (64)
      enum of Monitor-MWAIT exts supported     = false
      supports intrs as break-event for MWAIT  = false
      number of C0 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C1 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C2 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C3 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C4 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C5 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C6 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C7 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
   extended feature flags (0x80000001/edx):
      SYSCALL and SYSRET instructions        = false
      execution disable                      = true
      1-GB large page support                = false
      RDTSCP                                 = false
      64-bit extensions technology available = true
   Intel feature flags (0x80000001/ecx):
      LAHF/SAHF supported in 64-bit mode     = false
      LZCNT advanced bit manipulation        = false
      3DNow! PREFETCH/PREFETCHW instructions = false
   brand = "              Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz"
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = 0x0 (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = 0x0 (0)
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = 0x0 (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = 0x0 (0)
   L1 data cache information (0x80000005/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x0 (0)
      size (Kb)         = 0x0 (0)
   L1 instruction cache information (0x80000005/edx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 0x0 (0)
      size (Kb)         = 0x0 (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 unified cache information (0x80000006/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x40 (64)
      lines per tag     = 0x0 (0)
      associativity     = 8-way (6)
      size (Kb)         = 0x800 (2048)
   L3 cache information (0x80000006/edx):
      line size (bytes)     = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag         = 0x0 (0)
      associativity         = L2 off (0)
      size (in 512Kb units) = 0x0 (0)
   Advanced Power Management Features (0x80000007/edx):
      temperature sensing diode      = false
      frequency ID (FID) control     = false
      voltage ID (VID) control       = false
      thermal trip (TTP)             = false
      thermal monitor (TM)           = false
      software thermal control (STC) = false
      100 MHz multiplier control     = false
      hardware P-State control       = false
      TscInvariant                   = false
   Physical Address and Linear Address Size (0x80000008/eax):
      maximum physical address bits         = 0x24 (36)
      maximum linear (virtual) address bits = 0x30 (48)
      maximum guest physical address bits   = 0x0 (0)
   Logical CPU cores (0x80000008/ecx):
      number of CPU cores - 1 = 0x0 (0)
      ApicIdCoreIdSize        = 0x0 (0)
   (multi-processing synth): hyper-threaded (t=2)
   (multi-processing method): Intel leaf 1/4
   (APIC widths synth): CORE_width=0 SMT_width=1
   (APIC synth): PKG_ID=0 CORE_ID=0 SMT_ID=1
   (synth) = Intel Pentium 4 (Prescott N0), 90nm
```

Important bits (in my opinion)

1. CPU Architecture is **i686**
2. CPU op-mode can be **64-bit**
3. **LM** flag present
4. **width** is **64** bits
5. **VMX flag missing** - virtual machine extensions is not supported
6. Running version of **LTS Ubuntu Server** (outdated soon)
7. Running on **i686** platform
8. getconf LONG_BIT is outputing **32**

The 1-4 is good indication of x64 system capabilities, but point 5 is telling me what i can't  virtualize x64 guest systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization), and point 8 is telling me it is 32 bit operating system down here.

So which Ubuntu Server should i choose for an update? Is my machine capable of running 64 bit operating system? Or should i stay with 32 bit?

Comment: Why not try a 64bit OS, and then decide for yourself?

Comment: @mikewhatever well there is a chance to encounter this kind of error - "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot – please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU", which is unplesant to expirience. Also i'm quite curiout about subject, due to the fact i learn i686 architecture exists only today. It's like a unicorn to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the differences between i686 and x86_64 can be read on this page;

https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2006-October/msg03684.html

I think you definetely understand why you must use 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your should definitely use 32 bit i.e. i386 versions of both application software and OS. The i686 is not an explicit 64 bit computer. it's a later version of the i386 i.e. intel 8, 16, and 32 bit computers